# How to parsing data from delimited with dot and equal then add to listview

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listview, split, delimiter

I have some data like below

```
1000.2000=2A.3000.4000=1.5000=2,5B
```

need to parse the data and add to listview.
I already make the code with array but still not work and i need the solution.

```vb
Dim str As String = "1000.2000=2A.3000.4000=1.5000=2,5B"
Dim tabLine() As String
tabLine = str.Split("."c)
   For k As Integer = 0 To tabLine.Length - 1
       Dim listitem As ListViewItem
       listitem = lvContent.Items.Add("1")
       Dim sep As Char() = New Char(0) {}
       sep(0) = "="c
       For Each s As String In tabLine(k).Split(sep, 2)
           listitem.SubItems.Add(s)
       Next
   Next
```

the above code show me this result

```
-----------------
1000 |      | 
2000 |   2A | 
3000 |      |
4000 |   1  |
5000 | 2.5B |
```

I want the result like below

```
-----------------
1000 |   2 | A
2000 |   2 | A
3000 |   1 |
4000 |   1 |
5000 | 2.5 | B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't doing anything to split out that last part of the string. It only splits at the "." and then the "=". You haven't explained the rules for doing that split. The following code assumes that you want to split off the last character only if it is a letter.

```
Dim str As String = "1000.2000=2A.3000.4000=1.5000=2,5B"
Dim items As New List(Of ListViewItem)
Dim subNum As String = "", subLetter As String = ""

For Each val As String In str.Split("."c).Reverse
    Dim subs() As String = val.Split("=".ToCharArray, 2)
    Dim item As New ListViewItem(subs(0))

    If subs.Length > 1 Then
        subNum = subs(1)
        subLetter = ""
        If Char.IsLetter(subNum(subNum.Length - 1)) Then
            subLetter = subNum(subNum.Length - 1)
            subNum = subNum.Substring(0, subNum.Length - 1)
        End If
    End If

    item.SubItems.AddRange({subNum, subLetter})
    items.Add(item)
Next

items.Reverse()
lvContent.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray)
```

Comment: Last character is done with split, but that "1000.2000=2A" is have the same value. How to make it read as a same value then add it to the listview?

Comment: @Kenna I have edited my answer to address your comment and to apply the values after the "=" to earlier items with no "=". This produces the result that your question says you want.

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly.